# Copy contents of a routine to another location in memory

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, monkeypatching, delphi-6, detours

I want to copy the routine code in memory to another location. For e.g.

```
procedure OldShowMessage;
begin
  ShowMessage('Old message..');
end;
```

Say i want to copy the routine to another location in memory. I have declared something like

```
var
  lopShowMessage : procedure; // procedural pointer.
```

Some pseudo code would be like

```
// VirtualProtect(@OldShowMessage, <length of routine>, ..., ...);
// Allocate memory
// lopShowMessage := AllocMem(<length of routine>);
// Move(@OldMessage, Pointer(lopShowMessage)^, <length of routine>);
// FlushInstructioncache.....
```

I just want to know if there is any possibility of doing this. I have patched a routine to call a new routine, but since we place a JMP instruction using code detours, i may not be able to use the functionality provided in the old routine.

A reference for my previous question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978177/patch-routine-call-in-delphi)

Answer (score 0):

If you read up on the technical details of how [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) actually work, you will see that you can make use of the old routine by utilizing a `trampoline` as part of your detour.  You can then call the trampoline whenever you want to invoke the old routine.