# Delphi datetimepicker component value and enconded value difference

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, datetimepicker

I have a variable of type `TTime` and the value `EncodeTime(17, 00, 00,00)`, when I try to get the double value I get `0.070833333333`. I also have a datetimepicker component when I set it to `17:00:00` the double value I get is `0.70833333334`. It is not the same as the one that I enconded, so Im facing an issue whenever I try to compare the two values to see if they are equal. Why would it be that I am getting this error? I don't know if this is an error, but they are supposed to have the same double value.

Comment: Delphi version could very well be relevant. What is it? Sadly this is one of the great failings of the Delphi date/time format, the reliance on floating point rather than integer arithmetic.

Comment: Delphi Enterprise 7.0

Comment: More recent versions have improved date support. All the same, you are probably going to need to compare the two values up to a tolerance, say half a second.

Comment: See also [Comparing Time Values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23990987/576719).

Comment: @David: fully agreed. It can't be too hard to leave the integral part as-is (for days) and use another integer for the milliseconds. Or whatever.